# Virtualboxの上のUbuntuでCapsLock(Ctrlに入れ替えている)が押し続けられてしまう

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, key-mapping

WindowsホストのVirtualBox上のUbuntuでキーボードの設定を変更してCapsLockをCtrlとして使っているのですが、一度Capsを押すとずっとCtrlが有効になってしまいます。

私の環境ではCapsをCtrlとして使っているので、本来ならCapsLockキーを押している間だけCtrlが有効になってほしいのですが、一度CapsLockを押すと、CapsLockから手を放しても、Ctrlが押され続けていることになってしまいます。

そして、なぜか(Shift-Capsキー)を押すとCtrlが解除されます。

固定キー機能はoffになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Windows側のCapsLockの動作が影響しているように思うのですが、どうすればよいのでしょうか?

各バージョン
VirtualBox: 6.0.10
Host: Windows 10 Home 1903
Guest: Ubuntu 19.04
Gnome 3.32.1

Comment: 一点確認です。この現象は、Windowsホスト側でも同様の現象が発生していますか？

Comment: Windows上ではCapsとCtrlを入れ替えていないので起こっていません。

Comment: ubuntuのバージョンとデスクトップ環境の有無を教えて下さい

Comment: ubuntu19.04でデスクトップ環境を使っています(Gnome 3.32.1)

Comment: 直接の関連があるかは分かりませんが、VirtualBoxの機能として「ホストキー」というものがあり、ゲストOSの操作状態を抜けるためのキーで、Windowsだとデフォルトで「右Ctrlキー」に割り当てられています。

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntuにも固定キー機能が存在してそれが有効になっている可能性があります。

有効になっている場合は、外してください。

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-stickykeys.html

Comment: 固定キー機能を確認しましたがoffになっていました。